# C# WebApi, How to check if IHttpActionResult is OK or not(InternalServerError, Bad request etc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am doing an asp.net web api project, the return type of api is the interface "IHttpActionResult", my question is, for example, I have 2 webapi Get1() and Get2(), in Get2(), it will call Get1() first, how can I check if the return result of Get1() is OK or not, or how can I check if its httpstatuscode is 200?
I have searched somewhere and foun that in UnitTest, we can check the type but how can I achive this here? thank you

```
public IHttpActionResult Get1()
{
try
{
   JObject result=xxxxx;
   Return OK(result);
}catch(exception ex)
{
return InternalServerError();
}
}

public IHttpActionResult Get2()
{
try
{
   IHttpActionResult firstResult=Get1();
//how can I check firstResult is 200 or 500?
   Return OK();
}catch(exception ex)
{
return InternalServerError();
}
}
```

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  I would suggest not to call an action from within another action. create a service for the desired functionality and invoke that.

Comment: It's better, use the function instead to call action from another action.

Comment: When you can the using the HttpResultCode that you call the action with httRequest.

Comment: @Nkosi,  I thought that if I can check the IHttpActionResult, it will be very esay to call each other. You're right, it's better to create a service to handle this. Thanks so much

Comment: @A.R.F, yes it's better to create service to do it. I had focused too much on IHttpActionResult  instead of the what I should do. Thank you